# Convert date to milliseconds since epoch using Apache Derby

Tags: timestamp, derby, unix-timestamp, epoch

Is it possible to convert a TIMESTAMP field to number of milliseconds since epoch?

Something like:

```
select
    toEpoch(current_timestamp)
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32581936/193453 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11017780/193453, which are related, but not the same. It would be nice to collect all the "Derby stored procedure" questions and answers together somehow...

Comment: Hi Bryan, I agree. Just saw the Documentation feature go to Beta today. Perhaps we should use that?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Derby doesn't have a native function, but it's possible to create your own and call it from the database.

First, create the java method that will convert the date:

```
package DbExamples.StoredProcedures;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class DateUtilities {
    public static long toEpoch(Timestamp inputDate) {
        if (inputDate == null) {
            return 0L;
        }

        Long result = inputDate.getTime();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then inject the jar file into the database by running the following sql statement on the database:

```
CALL SQLJ.REMOVE_JAR('App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR('C:\dev\DbExamples\dist\DbExamples.jar', 'App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', 'App.StoredProcedures');
```

Now create the stored procedure in the database by running the following sql statement:

```
drop function toEpoch;
create function toEpoch(inputDate timestamp)
returns bigint
parameter style java no sql
language java external name 'DbExamples.StoredProcedures.DateUtilities.toEpoch';
```

Now you can run your query:

```
select
    toEpoch(current_timestamp)
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

select
    toEpoch(cast('2016-07-21 14:50:00' as timestamp))
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```